# need help understanding google endpoint javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-endpoints

How the object defined in the script element is referenced in other scripts? If somebody understands what's going on here, please explain.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=loadGapi">
  {
    "client": {},
      "googleapis.config": {
        root: API_URL
      }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Quentin. Sorry, no reputation to up vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text content of a script element with a `src` is added to the DOM but not executed as JavaScript.

The script, presumably, searches the DOM for the last `script` element, reads its text content and then passes that though `JSON.parse()`.